# Compare 2 arrays after removing the keys that does not exist in both using array functions

Tags: php, arrays

I have 2 arrays a and b which may or may not have similar values.

```
$a = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'John Doe', 'age' => 35);
$b = array('name' => 'John Doe', 'age' => 35);
```

I need to check whether the keys that are there in both the arrays contains same values or not using the array functions itself. Please help me.

NB: Array $a is always the parent array. If any key has to be popped, it would be only from $a.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following comparison based on [`array_intersect_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php):

```
$b == array_intersect_assoc($a, $b)
```

This will be `true` when all of the `$b` key/value pairs occur in `$a`, `false` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

Use: **[array_diff_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php)**

**Remove duplicate key:**

```
<?php
$a = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'John Doe', 'age' => 35);
$b = array('name' => 'John Doe', 'age' => 35);
$c = array_diff_key($a, $b);
print_r($c); //Array ( [id] => 1 )
?>
```

**Get duplicate key:**

Use: **[array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php)**

```
<?php
function array_duplicate_keys() {
    $arrays = func_get_args();
    $count = count($arrays);
    $dupes = array();
    // Stick all your arrays in $arrays first, then:
    for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
        for ($j = $i+1; $j < $count; $j++) {
            $dupes += array_intersect_key($arrays[$i], $arrays[$j]);
        }
    }
    return array_keys($dupes);
}
print_r(array_duplicate_keys($a, $b)); //Array ( [0] => name [1] => age )
?>
```

**Get duplicate key and value:**

```
<?php
function get_keys_for_duplicate_values($my_arr, $clean = false) {
    if ($clean) {
        return array_unique($my_arr);
    }

    $dups = $new_arr = array();
    foreach ($my_arr as $key => $val) {
      if (!isset($new_arr[$val])) {
         $new_arr[$val] = $key;
      } else {
        if (isset($dups[$val])) {
           $dups[$val][] = $key;
        } else {
           $dups[$val] = array($key);
        }
      }
    }
    return $dups;
}
print_r(get_keys_for_duplicate_values($a, $b)); 
//Array ( [id] => 1 [name] => John Doe [age] => 35 )
?>
```

Comment: Actually, I have mentioned in the question itself to use only array functions.

Answer (score 0):

If `$b` can have keys not present in `$a`, you can use [array_intersect_key](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) two times, with arguments in reversed order and check if both results are the same:

```
$ab = array_intersect_key($a, $b);
$ba = array_intersect_key($b, $a);
$allValuesEqual = ($ab == $ba);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:"it compare both key and value"

```
$result=array_diff_assoc($a1,$a2); //<-Compare both key and value, gives new array
```

example:

```
$a1=array("a"=>"red","b"=>"green","c"=>"blue");
$a2=array("a"=>"red","c"=>"blue","b"=>"pink");

$result=array_diff_assoc($a1,$a2);
print_r($result);

//result will be
Array ( [b] => green )
```